# py2exe: UnicodeDecodeError (can't decode byte 0xd1)

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze my application for Windows. It uses PyQt4 and was build on Python 2.7. All compilates and works good, but only on my PC. On other PC, which **doesn't have Python** installed, there is error:

```
 File "quirinus.py", line 4, in <module>
 File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
 File "bin\core.pyc", line 17, in <module>
 File "bin\xstring.pyc", line 19, in str2unicode
 File "encodings\utf_8.pyc", line 16, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Here is a code of my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
from glob import glob
data_files = [('Microsoft.VC90.CRT', glob(r'..\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*'))]
sys.path.append(r'..\Microsoft.VC90.CRT')
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

py2exe_options = dict(
  includes=['sip',
            'encodings',
            'encodings.ascii',
            'encodings.utf_8',
            'encodings.cp866'],
  excludes=['_ssl', 'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest',
    'tarfile', 'bz2', 'zipfile', 'optparse', 'pickle',
    'pywin', 'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon',
    'pywin.dialogs', 'pywin.dialogs.list',  'calendar',
    'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'tcl', '_gtkagg', '_tkagg',
    'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter'],
  dll_excludes=['msvcp90.dll', 'msvcr90.dll', 'msvcm90.dll',
    'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
    'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll'],
  compressed=True
)

setup(
  name='Quirinus',
  author='Dmitriy Selyutin',
  author_email='ghostmansd@google.com',
  description='Quirinus: Dictionary',
  version='0.1',
  windows = \
  [
    {
      'script': 'quirinus.py',
      'icon_resources': [(0, 'icons/icon.ico')]
    }
  ],
  options={'py2exe': py2exe_options},
  zipfile = None,
  data_files = data_files
  )
```

Here is a command to run freezing: `python.exe .\setup.py py2exe -b 1`

Every source file in my project has "encoding" line in the beginning:

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

As I think I've done everything to make Unicode work good. And it works on every computer which has Python. :-) But when computer doesn't have Python, application fails. Has anyone occured this problem?

P.S. I've also tried to freeze using PyInstaller (`python.exe .\pyinstaller.py -F -w`), but freezed application doesn't run. And yes, all my strings in source have the following form: u'string'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue has to do with whether or not python is installed on the other PC. I think you should take a second look at what the processor specs are on the other PC, in comparison to the specs on yours.

Freeze can be very processor specific, so you might have problems with cross processor compatibility

Comment: You've said beautiful words. I had understood that my code works on absolutely clean virtual Windows 7, but it doesn't work on usual Windows Vista.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you need further help with this question or have I answered it adequately?

Comment: It doesn't solve question. What must I do? Freeze application on all versions of Windows? I've only say that I've seen that you're right. But can it be solved? If yes, how? Re-freezing binary for every version of Windows?

Comment: Also, it's very strange that error is in Unicode. Not in Windows DLL's, which may differ between versions of Windows, but in Python's module.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but in your position, my next step would be to try `py2exe` directly, without freeze. I have had good cross compatibility with `py1exe` before, so hopefully that'll help you

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand you, could you explain, please?

Comment: From what you've mentioned in your posting, you have tried using py2exe with a bunch of flags that pertain to freeze. Try it without anything freeze. Try straight-up py2exe and see if that works any better